# Is deriving a class just for identification of the type a good idea?

Tags: oop, inheritance, refactoring

*Question is longer than normal, but I have tried to elaborate. Please bear with me and read the entire question, it might be an interesting problem*

I have a method A currently that accepts an object with two properties `List<X>` but representing two different entities and thus the property is named aptly R and S. Class structure is

```
class A
{
   List<X> R;
   List<X> S;
}
```

and now I have a method that accepts input of type A and works with both the (collections,method signature below)

```
public void updateMe(A objA)
{

}
```

now I have a case where I need to reuse this method but now the case is that I dont need to distinguish between the entities and thus have a single list, `List<X>` T.

Now my question is how do I refactor the method to work with a singleList, but still provide an ability to distinguish between the two lists in the earlier case.

My method will update these collections, thus either add to a list or remove from it.

My solution currently is to create new classes to represent the two distinct entities which derive from X and then pass the this base class list to my method and let the method update this base class and then while reading it I will be able to identify which object is what type.

Thus my new classes will be

```
public class X1:X
{
}

public class X2:X
{
}



class A
{
   List<X> R;
}
```

Is this the best solution or are there any other approaches that I could take here.. I just dont seem to like the idea of extending a class just to identify the type without adding any properties..

Comment: How is it that the same method needs to distinguish the two lists in one case and doesn't care in the other case?

Comment: the consumer of the method in one case renders the two list identifying them separately and in the other case it doesnt..

Answer (score 0):

I would say, either:
1. Use ENUM :)
2. Make classes Y&Z to extend abstract X with abstract method getList(). But this for sure is an overkill for the simple case. So, back to 1 - just use the enum :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the objective is to achieve a form of polymorphism on the content of the class. In this sense you should isolate a class for the internal contents, so my answer focuses on the objective that leads to your question rather than question itself.

In general, for a priori of your question, i'd say that the distinction between the two collections, each representing a different entity, is not a matter of the representative type, assuming it is correct, but responsibility of the caller.
My answer follows this path and however realize a variable inner representation and update logic in a strongly-typed way, with static polimorphism (omitting, for reasons of time, explain you this choice).

As a rule of decision whether to use a subclass of `X`, you should ask yourself: `updateMe` logic that operates the update of `List<X> R` and `List<X> S`, it does according to details of objects `X`?

I assume from your question that this is not always of two lists and my solution generalize on the type of collections too.
I hope to give you a starting point. If I guessed your request i'll illustrate more.

```cpp
template <class staticPolimorphicAInnerT>
class A 
{
    public:
        void updatMe (const A& ref) {
            // <do something pre if necessary>
            updateInnerMe (A.innerObj);
            // <do some other post if necessary>
        }

        void updateInnerMe (const staticPolimorphicAInnerT& innerRef) {
            innerObj.updateMe (innerRef);
            // or better: 
            // inner_update_method (innerRef)
        }

    private:
        // is used to request the static polymorphism
        typedef void (staticPolimorphicAInnerT::* inner_update_method) (const staticPolimorphicAInnerT&)
        staticPolimorphicAInnerT innerObj; 
        //<something more i hope> 

}

template <class T>
class AInnerFirst
{
    public:
        void updatMe (const AInnerFirst& ref) {
            // <do something with R>
            // <do something with S>
        }

    private:
        List<T> R;
        List<T> S;
}

template <class T>
class AInnerSecond 
{
    public:
        void updatMe (const AInnerSecond& ref) {
            // <do something with W>
        }

    private:
         Vector<T> W;
}
```